# How to access manually created index in pouchdb find

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am pretty new to pouchDB and couchDB. I've trying to use pouchdb find but having some problems.

I have created a view "test" and source -

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.name, doc.occupation);
}
```

[image]

and when i run this -

```
localDB.query('test/test').then(function (res) {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Everything works as expected.

But when i try pouchdb find -

```
localDB.find({
  selector: {name: 'kittens'}
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I got following error -

> Error: couldn't find a usable index. try creating an index on: name.

---

If i create index by

```
localDB.createIndex({
  index: {
    fields: ['name']
  }
});
```

only then pouchdb find code works. But when i manually created an index (shown in image above) then it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pouchdb-find uses the new "Mango" query language, which is different from map/reduce. Mango is only supported in CouchDB 2.0+ and PouchDB Server, *not* CouchDB 1.x.

So at this time you will need to either use CouchDB 2.0 or PouchDB Server with pouchdb-find if you want it to work on both the client and the server, or you will need to use regular map/reduce instead and avoid pouchdb-find.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. Didn't knew that. I can see only 1.6 version in CouchDB while browsing from windows and i thought it is latest. I prefer to skip pouchdb find in this case.